# Xamarin.Forms - Is it possible to download files from website in webview?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms Application for Android and iOS I have a WebView that presents a website. There it is possible to download some files. The file is returned from the website as an application/octet-stream. In the native browser on Android or iOS the file will downloaded automatically.

My problem is that I not receive the returned datas for the selected file from the Xamarin.Forms WebView. Are there any solutions to download the file? I want to open that file after downloading with
`Launcher.OpenAsync(filepath)`?

Comment: intercept the navigation event when the user clicks on a download link and then use HttpClient to perform the download

Comment: I have implemented the navigated and navigating event but no event is fired when I click on the download link. Is there a way to get the response when the download link is clicked?

Comment: I have no idea what your "download link" is.  It could be an `<a/>`, some javascript implementation, or a hundred other things.

Comment: Oh sorry @Jason! The download link is an `<a/>` with a javascript as href. This was automatically created by ASP.NET.
The C# code in ASP.NET to return the file is the following:
`this.Session["DownloadesFile"] = file;
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.TransmitFile(file);
...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [custom renderer for webview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview) to achieve this in Xamarin Android.

Then make sure WebView has enabled javascript and the WebViewClient is set correctly.

```
web.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
web.SetWebViewClient(new WebviewClient());
```

Then set a [SetDownloadListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setDownloadListener(android.webkit.DownloadListener)) for `Android.Webkit.WebView`, Then use [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) to download the file. Due to [the Android 11 storage limitation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage). I store download file to the application's top-level directory with [Xamarin.Essentials: File System Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android).

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.WebView), typeof(MyWebviewCustomRenderer))]
namespace App11.Droid
{
    internal class MyWebviewCustomRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebviewCustomRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                var webView = new global::Android.Webkit.WebView(Android.App.Application.Context);
                webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                webView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
                webView.SetDownloadListener(new CustomDownloadListener());
                this.SetNativeControl(webView);
                var source = e.NewElement.Source as UrlWebViewSource;
                if (source != null)
                {
                    webView.LoadUrl(source.Url);
                }
           
        }
    }
    public class CustomDownloadListener : Java.Lang.Object, IDownloadListener
    {
        public void OnDownloadStart(string url, string userAgent, string contentDisposition, string mimetype, long contentLength)
        {
            try
            {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
                request.AllowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.SetNotificationVisibility(DownloadVisibility.VisibleNotifyCompleted);
                // if this path is not create, we can create it.
                string thmblibrary = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory + "/download";
                if (!Directory.Exists(thmblibrary))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(thmblibrary);
                request.SetDestinationInExternalFilesDir(Android.App.Application.Context, FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "download");
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.App.Application.DownloadService);
                dm.Enqueue(request);
               
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

Relative thread here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/497906/how-to-download-files-like-the-native-browser-with.html .